# Store value temporarily

Tags: java, android

I am working on showing information on textview. I have two tables which each containing list of informations. If I click "table A" button it shows the 1st information and if I click it again it shows the 2nd information. Then if I click the "table b" button then the 1st information of b is shown and it increases as the number of clicks increases. But if I click "table a" button again, then it must show the second information, not the third one. I am not getting any idea how to do that one. Please help me. I am new. My piece of code for that is as follows

```
case "table a":
    if (j>4) {
        j=1;
    }
    text.setText(String.valueOf(j));
    j++;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "A table information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

case "table b":
    if (i>6) {
        i=1;
    }
    text.setText(String.valueOf(j));
    i++;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "B table information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;
```

The problem I am facing is, if I click the "table a". it shows the 1st information. And then if I click "table b" then it shows the 1st information of table b. Then if I click the "table a" it is showing 2nd. I want it to show 1st information, if I come back from "table b" to "table a". Please give some suggestion.

Comment: If you show some more code, maybe the whole class, I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Java is by default zero based, thus if you reset an array, you should set the value to 0, not 1.

```
if(j>4){
   j=0;
}
```

As I understand it, you want to show the same thing that was previously shown on table A if you switch back to it. The best way to do that is to keep track of the active state, and only change the value if the active state is the current one. The best way to do this is with some sort of an enum. This code might need a few tweeks, such as using TABLE_SELECTED.A instead of just TABLE_SELECTED, but it should work with such tweaks done.

```
private enum TABLE_SELECTED{A,B};
TABLE_SELECTED activeTAble=A;
case "table a":  if(aIndex>4){
                aIndex=0;
            }
            text.setText(String.valueOf(aIndex));
            if(activeTable==A)
                aIndex++;
            activeTable=A
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

case "table b":   if(bIndex>6){
                bIndex=1;
            }
            text.setText(String.valueOf(bIndex));
            if(activeTable==B)
                bIndex++;
            activeTable=B
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: if I am in 4th message of "table a" and I clicked "table b". If I again click "table a", I need to get 4th information. Not to reset.

Comment: Oh, then use the same variable, as the other answer suggests.

Comment: :But as u have suggested, the value of index will increase at the end right. Then it will show the next information next time I change the table.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I understand what you are talking about now. Will edit my answer appropriately.